# How would I edit an existing model field entry?

Tags: python, django

I have a model with a charfield that keeps tracks of the ongoing status of a bill:

```
from django.db import models
import datetime


class due(models.Model):

    PAYED = (

    ("paid", "Paid"),
    ("un-paid", "Un-Paid")

    )

    bill = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    amount = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    status = models.CharField(choices=PAYED, max_length=128)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Bill"

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} for {} is: {}".format(self.bill, self.amount,   self.status)
```

I'm going to render every bill I have through a django template to easily see it. The problem I'm having is I'm not sure how on the same page I can edit the status of the bill.

What would I need to do on the back end to make that functionality through the use a button or a form?

Comment: You can make a view that marks the status as paid/unpaid, and then implement buttons in the template that query this view (for example through an AJAX call)

Comment: Hi @Vildjharta let me know if you'd like a full page refresh when you update a bill, but William Van Onsem's right - you'll need to use some sort of AJAX call to send data to your server without a full page refresh.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem could I use jquery instead of AJAX?

Comment: @MichealJRoberts I would like a full page refresh

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer on this ?

Comment: @RaoufM, not anymore. I'm just refactoring to make my questions more useful for others.